# ¿Cómo hacer comentarios multi línea en MASM?

Tags: masm

Para hacer comentarios utilizo punto y coma

```
;esto es un comentario
```

Pero si el comentario es de varias líneas tengo que poner un punto y coma por cada línea.

¿Alguna forma de hacer comentarios multi línea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con:

```
COMMENT #
 Línea 1 de comentario
 Línea 2 de comentario
 #
```

Puedes utilizar el delimitador (en este caso `#`) que quieras, siempre y cuando sea el mismo en la primera y en la última línea.